# Javascript - checkbox reading value from array of objects

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked, unchecked

I need to get my checkboxes in todo list read from object in array if task is complete or not. And stay checked when they're complete and unchecked or not.

```
const todos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Nakupit',
    description: 'Mlieko, syr, vajcia',
    completed: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Umyt auto',
    description: '+ povysavat',
    completed: true,
  },
]
```

This is the array and i tried on checkbox something like this. And variations, unable to get it work and changing array or value from array making checkbox ,checked, if complete

```
 toDoCheckbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (toDoCheckbox.checked = true) {
       return todos.completed === true
        
      } else {
       return todos.completed === false
      }
    });
```

Can anyone help with it?

Comment: Use the `event` param of the listener function (first argument) and access `event.currentTarget` to get the item that was clicked...

Comment: `todos` is an array, it doesn't have a `.completed` property. Also your funtion returns a value, but it doesn't actually *do* anything.

Comment: What is `toDoCheckbox` ? Typically there would be one checkbox per item. Show us more code as per [mcve]

Comment: Also note you are using `=` for a comparison but that is an assignment operator

Comment: here is whole thing i have https://playcode.io/637457/

Comment: Always post the relevant code in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `todos` state by looking it up by its `id` and flipping its `completed` status.

I added the button to request re-rendering. This will re-build the checkboxes using the current state.

```js
const todos = [{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Nakupit',
  description: 'Mlieko, syr, vajcia',
  completed: false,
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Umyt auto',
  description: '+ povysavat',
  completed: true,
}]

const main = () => {
  const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-render')
  btn.addEventListener('click', reRender)
  renderTodos()
}

const reRender = (e) => {
  renderTodos()
}

const onCheck = (e) => {
  const id = parseInt(e.currentTarget.dataset.id, 10)
  const found = todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  if (found) {
    found.completed = !found.completed // Flip status
  }
}

const renderTodos = () => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container')

  container.innerHTML = '' // Clear

  todos.forEach(todo => {
    let wrapper = document.createElement('div')
    let label = document.createElement('label')
    let checkbox = document.createElement('input')

    wrapper.classList.add('checkbox-wrapper')
    label.textContent = todo.title
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
    checkbox.checked = todo.completed
    checkbox.dataset.id = todo.id
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', onCheck)

    wrapper.appendChild(label)
    wrapper.appendChild(checkbox)
    container.appendChild(wrapper)
  })
}

main()
```

```css
.checkbox-wrapper label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<br />
<button class="btn-render">Re-render</button>
```

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl , i got it working like this. But it doesn't work other way around. I need to change array value when clicking checkbox. Not render checkbox after value i change in the array

Comment: @MiroslavValkovič This does change the status of the array values... See: `found.completed = !found.completed`